# How to add method to declared class in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add a custom method to an existing class exported by an external library. This class is defined like this: `export declare class Site`.

I tried declaring a module using the package name, but when I add the interface, typescript complains with: `'Site' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`.

This is the typing I tried:

```
declare module '@pnp/sp' {
  interface Site {
    getChanges: (query: any) => Promise<any>;
  }
}
```